# Navigate to default page from OnResume()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, onresume

In Xamarin forms, the OnResume event handler is on the Application class, which is not a NavigationPage, so you cannot do any navigation in OnResume. When my app resumes, if it has been asleep for more than 30 mins, I want it to go back to its home page, not resume to the page where it went to sleep. I have got the 30 minute trap in the OnResume, but I can't do the navigation. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: do you have any code snippet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

by default, in a Forms app, you're storing the `MainPage` which should be a `NavigationPage` in this case.

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new NavigationPage {
```

So you can use it to get to the `Navigation` object.

```
protected override async void OnResume ()
{
    var nav = MainPage.Navigation;

    // you may want to clear the stack (history)
    await nav.PopToRootAsync (true);

    // then open the needed page (I'm guessing a login page)
    await nav.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't realize I could access the MainPage object. You have thoughtfully suggested clearing the stack history, however when I try this I get a syntax error: ElementAt is not a method on NavigationStack. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: you'll need to add `using System.Linq;` Xamarin Studio is not always helping with the missing Linq lib, because they're Extensions Methods probably, but still annoying ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try updating your OnResume method to look like this:

```
protected async override void OnResume ()
{
    await MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync (true);
}
```

Comment: Nice simple answer. Many thanks. I would have ticked it as correct but Benoit got there first.

Comment: it's way better, thanks, I updated the answer for reference