# Navigate the user a to specific page based on the deep link used to open the app in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I'm trying to navigate the user to a specific page based on the deep link URL they used to open the app. I'm unsure in which lifecycle method to do this URL check and navigation. I was thinking of doing it in the OnNewIntent in MainActivity but I can't figure out how to open a specific page from here.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be highly appreciated.

I tried to open a page from OnResume method as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104810/20868533) but what happens is the navigation bar at the top says that page changed to the correct one but the page content doesn't change.

My App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    CheckoutSuccess success;

    public App(LandingPage landingPage, NavigationPage _navigationPage, CheckoutSuccess _success)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        success = _success;

        _navigationPage.PushAsync(landingPage);
        MainPage = _navigationPage;
    }

    protected override async void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        var nav = MainPage.Navigation;
        await nav.PopToRootAsync(true);
        await nav.PushAsync(success); // Injected the successPage in App constructor

    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a static `NavigationService` type class, where you can set a string which is the path taken from the incoming URL from the activity. For more details, you can refer to [this solution](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3788#issuecomment-1297529268);